# why plants cannot use atmospheric nitrogen?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

Earth's atmosphere constitutes 78% of Nitrogen, then why do plants need to absorb Nitrogen from the soil. Why couldn't it possible for them to absorb the atmospheric Nitrogen like they do in the case of CO2.

Most of the plants relies on other sources to fix their Nitrogen, why couldn't be there a single plant which can absorb atmospheric Nitrogen ?

Is there any ancient plant which is considered to be using atmospheric Nitrogen ?

> I have done a simple research, I could only find that previously
>   atmosphere is not so abundant with Nitrogen and plants developed
>   mechanisms to use Nitrogen fixed in soil. So now they are following
>   the same mechanism when Nitrogen is abundant in the atmosphere. Is
>   this a valid answer ?

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I had seen that question while creating this thread.....but the answers are some what vague....I have came through some other answers but I cant find any reliable references in the answers given to that question.

Comment: Atmospheric nitrogen is inert and poorly soluble in water. It has to be converted to a soluble form before absorption.

Comment: @WYSIWYG: Can you please expand and add it as an answer

Comment: @Jay - the question (and the answer) is not "vague".

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I don't know the exact word for calling those answers which are having no references.

Comment: I agree with @anongoodnurse that the question is a duplicate. The answers there are, however, not satisfactory in that they do not give a clear cut answer. Hence, putting a bounty on that question would help. I understand 50 rep may seem a lot, but it would be the way to go here.